# Extract text which resides outside html-body

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Ho can I extract something which resides outside html body and doesn't have any tag using selenium webdriver
for eg. I would like to extract the Entity_ID from below page source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html ......">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form....>
         ......
       </form>
   </body>
   <!--
     Host Name: ********.com
     Interaction ID: 111111111
     Iteration: 1
     Entity ID: 111111111111
     ApplicationID: 11111111111
     Image Location: **********
     Operating Environment: staging
     Page Name: **************
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WebDriver#getPageSource()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) method:

```
        driver.get("http://your.page.com")

        String pageSrc = driver.getPageSource();

        int idx = pageSrc.indexOf("Entity ID:" );
        if( idx>= 0) {
            System.out.println(pageSrc.substring(idx, pageSrc.indexOf("\n", idx)));
        }
```